# vs c++ error list Lnk1104 .obj with strange file path

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, linker

I'm new to VS VC++ and OpenCV also. I'm writting a simpal code example to show image. But i'm stuck right in VS when compile with error in Error List:

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'cv_winapp1_32.obj'
I don't understand why File Column show D:\cpp\cv_winapp1_32\cv_winapp1_32\LINK (but not path + file name cv_winapp1_32.obj as i hope) and infact, cv_winapp1_32.obj was created in other path  D:\cpp\cv_winapp1_32\cv_winapp1_32\Debug

I searched all Lnk1104 on Internet and StackOveflow also but i couldn't find the answer for my case.

If i don't put cv_winapp1_32.obj; to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, i will have Error    LNK2019 unresolved external symbol (to cv::Mat  of OpenCV).

Please help me resolve issue !
Thanks You All !

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Hi All,

Please update to whom have same issue.

I miss-understand C++ build flow, 'cv_winapp1_32.obj' was created before C++ link step, and i should not put 'cv_winapp1_32.obj' to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.

Come back to Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol: i must put all OpenCV include folders to: C++ >Additionally  Include  Directory.

Best Regards!